# Submit Apple Watch app icons error ITMS-90391

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-watch

I get the ERROR ITMS-90391: Missing Icons error when trying to submit an app with a Apple Watch app & extension target.

Here's what I've checked so far, but nothing works:

- The iOS app asset catalog does not contain Watch icons for AppIcon.
- The iOS app asset catalog has only the iOS app as target membership
- The WatchApp target that also includes the storyboard has a asset catalog that only contains icons for Apple Watch (version 2 and newer)
- The WatchApp asset catalog has only the WatchApp as target membership.
- The extension does only contains icons for the complication and has only the extension as target member ship.
- Each target has the correct asset catalog entry specified for the icon
- Info.plist for the WatchApp does not contain entries for CFBundleIconFiles
- I've also tried to add entries for CFBundleIconFiles in info.plist, but that doesn't work either.
- Icons does not contain an alpha channel
- Icons have correct dimensions
- If I open the app package I can see the icon files in the bundle and entries in the generated info.plist, but I noticed that @2x.png, @3px.png suffixes are removed.

I generate the app package using Xcode 9 on High Sierra. I upload it using Application Loader, since Xcode 9 picks the wrong team when I try to upload from Xcode.

This is driving me crazy. Have tried to find a solution for several days now.

Comment: I have this too. I think maybe an Xcode bug ?